# Python class function as dictionary entries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a python script to generate Tableau Data Extract (.tde) files given a MySQL query.

Writing a row to the `.tde` requires writing each column individually with a `set<column_type>(column_no, column_val)` function.  For example, writing the integer 3 to the 2nd column in the row would look like `row.setInteger(1, 3)`. Writing the word 'Bob' to the 4th column in the row would look like `row.setCharString(3, 'Bob')`.

As I iterate over the columns, I want to call the correct `set<column_type>()` function based on the column type.  I keep these functions in a dictionary:

```
tde_set_type_function_map = {
    Type.DATE: Row.setDate,
    Type.DATETIME: Row.setDateTime,
    Type.DOUBLE: Row.setDouble,
    Type.CHAR_STRING: Row.setCharString,
    Type.INTEGER: Row.setInteger,
```

}

```
for row in mysql:
      # Create new row
    tde_row = Row(table_def)   # Pass the table definition to the constructor
    for colno, col in enumerate(row):
        col_type = table_def.getColumnType(colno)
        setType = tde_set_type_function_map[col_type]
        print setType # e.g. <unbound method Row.setCharString>
        print type(setType) # e.g. <type 'instancemethod'>
        tde_row.setType(colno, col)
    tde_table.insert(tde_row)
```

After `tde_row.setType(colno, col)`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'setType'
```

I've used functions within dictionaries before, but never when they belong to an object.  Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: But you're not using the function from the dictionary; that's assigned to the variable setType, but you're using the setType attribute of tde_row, which is completely unrelated.

Comment: Exactly.  How do I go about using the function from dictionary and not the unrelated, nonexistent SetType attribute?

Comment: Just call it, like any other function: `setType(tde_row)`.

Comment: duh.  I tried `setType(self=tde_row, colno, col)`, but Python didn't like the `self=`.  Thanks. Do u want to create an answer and I'll accept?  Or should I delete question...